# Django: If objects queryset is empty write zero instead. I solve this with numpy but I want a direct solution in the queryset

Tags: django

I think there should be an easier and more elegant solution but I cannot find it. I have the following in views.py. As you can see I achieve want I want with numpy but I want a direct solution:

```
 myarray = np.asarray(MyDatabase.objects.filter(
                status='user').values_list('name','age').order_by('age')) 
 
 if myarray.size==0:
   myarray=np.zeros((1,2))
```

What I want is to set zeros when the object queryset is empty, e.g., in this case status=user is filtered from my Database Table and let's assume that no status=user exists, then I want 'name' and 'age' to show 0 as outputs.
I did it but I just dislike using the extra lines. I wonder if there is a way to directly ouput zeros when the object is empty.
I would appreciate it if you share your solution.

Thanks

Comment: why not using `len(myqueryset)`?

Comment: it is also possible... however, the solution given by dani herrera is what I was looking for, adding 'or' simplifies everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self explained:

```py
# db values
query = (
    MyDatabase
    .objects
    .filter(status='user')
    .values_list('name','age')
    .order_by('age')
)

# set db values or zeros if no values
myarray = query or [(0, 0)]
```